# How to make sort from document using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

below is the `document_1.xml`

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>30</Quantity>
    </product> 
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>20</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and `document_2.xml` is

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>Pen</name>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    </product> 
    <product>
        <name>Pencil</name>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Bag</name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </product>
</products>
```

and `document.xml` is

```
<products>
</products>
```

Below is my xsl, i used to join `document_1.xml` and `document_2.xml` to the `document.xml`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('document_1.xml')/*/product"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('document_2.xml')/*/product"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need output like below

1. Sort by Quantity ASC

   ```
   <products>
       <product>
           <name>Bag</name>
           <Quantity>2</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Pencil</name>
           <Quantity>5</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Pen</name>
           <Quantity>10</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Pencil</name>
           <Quantity>20</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Bag</name>
           <Quantity>25</Quantity>
       </product>
       <product>
           <name>Pen</name>
           <Quantity>30</Quantity>
       </product>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is `xsl:sort` tag , but it can be used only inside `xsl:for-each` loop - eg.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('document_1.xml')/*/product|document('document_2.xml')/*/product">
  <xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number" />
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: tks, where i can place this in my xsl ?

Comment: xsl:template ... if you don't know much about xsl - try to learn it first on simplier applications

Comment: i can use this sort in side <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"><xsl:sort select="Quantity" data-type="number" />
</xsl:apply-templates> like this?